# HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.

Tags: iis-7, reverse-proxy, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy with IIS 7.5. I want an incoming request that matches a certain URL pattern to be served by Tomcat. I have used the tutorial here to configure it.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

My settings are as below:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>                
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*/(Locations|FacetedSearch|LocationPage)/.*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://search.xxx.com/{R:1}" />
                 <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" replace="true" /> 
                </serverVariables>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://search.xxx.com/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://dev.xxx.com/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    <tracing>
```

HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the content of the HTTP response is encoded ("deflate").

Answer (score 6):

I just hit this issue as well, and I found this solution helpful: https://www.saotn.org/iis-outbound-rules-with-gzip-compression/

Basically, on inbound requests the HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING header gets stashed into a temporary header, and then gets restored back on the outbound rewrite rule.

In the case the link goes dead, here's the steps:

1. Through the IIS Manager GUI on the server node in the left pane, navigate to URL Rewrite
2. Click *View Server Variables* in the right pane
3. Add two *Allowed Server Variables*:

> ```
> HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING
> HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING
> ```

4. Back in URL Rewrite options for the Server, click on *View Preconditions* in the right pane. Add a new precondition (I named it *NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding*)
5. Set the Condition Input to *{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}* and the Pattern to ".+" (no quotes).
6. On the *inbound* rewrite rule that is causing the error, add the following to *Server Variables* (you'll find it underneath the *Conditions* section):

> ```
> Server Variable Name: HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING
> Value: {HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}
>
> Server Variable Name: HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING
> Value: ""
> ```

7. On the *outbound* rewrite rule, add the precondition created from steps 4-5 to the *Precondition* section of the rule (it should be populated in the drop-down box)

In the case that you only need this functionality on a single site, you can add the precondition at the site-level instead of the server-level.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web config

```
 <serverVariables>
    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />          
 </serverVariables>
```

or disable dynamic compression in iis

Comment: What is "this"? Could you add this, please!?

Comment: eh :) check this out: http://www.wrapcode.com/infrastructure/configure-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-and-arr-for-iis/

Comment: it help me to add  reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Rew
rite /v LogRewrittenUrlEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
to my test registry and you will need to under Allowed Server  Variables the following: HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING, HTTP_CUST, HTTP_HOST, HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS, HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_SERVER_POST,HTTPS

Comment: Please edit you answer rather than putting this in the comments :)

Comment: can you please tell me why we need to add `serverVariables` in web.config file? i am also getting http error for outbound rule. so should i add `serverVariables` ? under which node i need to add serverVariables in web.config file ? please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

find "compress" in IIS,then remove the dynamic content compression and static content compression.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling dynamic and static content compression from the site responsible for reverse proxying the requests AND the site that is being proxied fixed this error for me.

To put it in other words - if server X is routing requests to server Y, then disable dynamic and static content compression on the sites on both server X and Y.